# tinyMCE paste as word

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Hello:
Does anyone know how to paste as Word into the newest version of tinyMCE (3-3-9-3)? Thanks.

Comment: you can just copy-paste from the Word to Tinymce?

Comment: please rethink this question and make it somewhat more clear!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of a number of versions ago, pasting from Word into a TinyMCE window is as easy as copying the Word document (control-c or x) and just pasting it into the TinyMCE window.  It should then convert the office code into HTML.

EDIT:

In order to preserve your office stylings, you need to add paste_retain_style_properties to your TinyMCE.init declaration.

Example:

`tinyMCE.init({

     ....


     paste_retain_style_properties : "margin, padding, width, height, font-size, font-weight, font-family, color, text-align, ul, ol, li, text-decoration, border, background, float, display",

     ....

});`

Comment: yeah but how do you keep the font families and color? There's some javascript out there on Google, but they have line numbers and it looks like the newest code has it all on one line.

Comment: It's a configuration setting when you first init TinyMCE: paste_retain_style_properties .  For example, for a project I am working on now, ours reads (within TinyMCE.init):  

paste_retain_style_properties : "margin, padding, width, height, font-size, font-weight, font-family, color, text-align, ul, ol, li, text-decoration, border, background, float, display",

Comment: If you want to ensure you get all the properties, just put "all" or "*" -- see the tinymce plugin documentation for the [paste plugin](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin:paste).